# IIS Advanced Logging - Scripting Out Filters via Powershell

Tags: powershell, iis, iis-advanced-logging

I am already scripting the majority of the IIS Advanced Logging setup via powershell.

#### Goal

I'd like to automate the `<filters>` section of the root server logDefinition.  I've tried multiple commands, none seeming to work.

Ultimately, the `system.webServer/advancedLogging/server/logDefinitions/logDefinition[@baseFileName='%COMPUTERNAME%-Server']` section should have some XML like this:

```
<filter>
    <condition operator="And">
        <condition operator="And">
            <expression field="URI-Stem" operator="NotEquals" value="/serverstatuscheck" caseSensitive="false" regularExpression="false" />
        </condition>
    </condition>
</filter>
```

#### Attempt 1

I tried the following 2 commands in powershell - they didn't give me any errors, but didn't have any effect either:

```
Add-WebConfiguration -Filter "system.webServer/advancedLogging/server/logDefinitions/logDefinition[@baseFileName='%COMPUTERNAME%-Server']/filter" -Value @{operator='And'}
```

And

```
Add-WebConfiguration -Filter "system.webServer/advancedLogging/server/logDefinitions/logDefinition[@baseFileName='%COMPUTERNAME%-Server']/filter" -Value @{elementTagName="condition";operator='And'}
```

Then I tried the following command, and got the error *Add-WebConfiguration : Key value is missing.* (though I am not sure which key it is looking for):

```
Add-WebConfiguration -Filter "system.webServer/advancedLogging/server/logDefinitions/logDefinition[@baseFileName='%COMPUTERNAME%-Server']/filter/condition" -Value @{operator='And'}
```

#### Attempt 2

My next attempt was to use the [Configuration Editor](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/managing-your-configuration-settings/using-configuration-editor-generate-scripts) to generate a script.  So I went and made my changes, clicked **Generate Script** and pulled out the Powershell that it generated.  Here is what that looks like:

```
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.webServer/advancedLogging/server/logDefinitions/logDefinition[@baseFileName='%COMPUTERNAME%-Server']/filter/condition" -name "." -value @{}

Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.webServer/advancedLogging/server/logDefinitions/logDefinition[@baseFileName='%COMPUTERNAME%-Server']/filter/condition/condition[]" -name "." -value @{field='URI-Stem';operator='NotEquals';value='/serverstatuscheck'}
```

But that didn't work either.  I got the same *Add-WebConfiguration : Key value is missing.* error as above.

#### My Question

Can anyone nudge me in the right direction?  I feel like I am close, but have been hitting walls.  I can manually configure this just fine.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3):

After many tries, try this one:

```
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter "/system.webServer/advancedLogging/server/logDefinitions/logDefinition[@baseFileName='%COMPUTERNAME%-Server']/filter/condition" -name "." -value @{field='URI-Stem';operator='NotEquals';value='/serverstatuscheck'}
```

Comment: Thanks ! This works, what is the parameter to enable reg exp ?